# how to do multiple sub string replace at same time

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace, substr

I want to do multiple sub string replace based on starting and length. Currently I have an array with values

```
(user-id,replace-name,starting,length)

my string: "Hi Rameez plz call charlie"

sample array : array('123','Rameez Rami',4,6),  array('124','Charlie Russet',20,7)
```

And what I want is

Rameez to
[Rameez](http://foo.com)
charlie to [Charlie](http://foo.com)

my current code is

```
$linkAddedDescription=Input::get('description');
            foreach ($descriptionMapArray as $key=> $taggedItem) {
            //print_r($taggedItem);die;
                $tagWordStarting=$taggedItem[0];
                $tagWordLength=$taggedItem[1];
                $taggedItemData=$taggedItem[3];
                $descriptionTagLink='<a href="'.URL::to("/").'/user/profile/'.$taggedItemData->id.'">'.$taggedItemData->name.'</a>';

                $linkAddedDescription=substr_replace($linkAddedDescription,$descriptionTagLink,$tagWordStarting,$tagWordLength); 
              //break;
            }
            print_r($linkAddedDescription);die;
```

Comment: Please post your expected output its unclear

Comment: i dont want to use the find and replace logic. i want to replace the string based on the starting and legth provided in the array

Comment: i currently use substr_replace(string,replacement,start,length)  function but the problem is, when the first replace is made the length for whole string changes so at the time of replacing second string it checks for for given starting and length values but replaces in wrong position due to the first text change.

Comment: If it's possible I would forget about doing the substr thing because as you said, you're depending on the item being in a specific position. Is it possible to add `{name}` or something to the additional string? Then you can use `str_replace`.

Comment: its not possible iam using this  for "user tagging in post" like facebook.

Comment: currently i get in which position user was tagged

Comment: But like you said, the lenght of the string changes when you replace one item. So for the second you would put it in the wrong place. Unless you check how much shorter/longer the string got and update the startposition of the second item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$descriptionMapArray=json_decode(Input::get('ideaTagDescriptionMap'));
        $str=Input::get('description');
        $startofsub=0;
        $taggedDescription='';
        foreach ($descriptionMapArray as $key=> $taggedItem) {
            $tagWordStarting=$taggedItem[0];
            $tagWordLength=$taggedItem[1];
            $taggedItemData=$taggedItem[3];
            $descriptionTagLink='<a href="/user/profile/'.$taggedItemData->id.'">'.$taggedItemData->name.'</a>';

            $tolen=($tagWordStarting+$tagWordLength);
            $to=$tolen-$tagWordStarting;
            $v=$tolen-$startofsub;
            $sbstr=substr($str,$startofsub,$v);
            $sbstr=substr_replace($sbstr,$descriptionTagLink,($tagWordStarting-$startofsub),$tagWordLength);
            $taggedDescription.=$sbstr;
            $startofsub=$tagWordStarting+$tagWordLength;
        }    
        if($startofsub < strlen(Input::get('description'))){
            $lst_part=strlen(Input::get('description'))-$startofsub;
            $taggedDescription.=substr($str,$startofsub,$lst_part);
        }
        echo '<br/>RESULT:-'.$taggedDescription;
        die;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am understanding your question correctly. If so: have your string ready with the spots you want to fill in in curly braces:

```
$outputString = 'Hi {name} plz call {othername}';
$firstPerson = array('123', 'Rameez', 4, 6);
$secondPerson = array('132', 'Charlie', 3, 8);
```

Then use `str_replace` to fill them with your data:

```
$outputString = str_replace('{name}', $firstPerson[1]);
$outputString = str_replace('{othername}', $secondPerson[1]);
```

(The string/arrays are an example of course, this depends on your data/wishes)

Comment: hi i want to replace based on starting and length provided in the array and not based on characters.plz help.

Comment: i currently use substr_replace(string,replacement,start,length) function but the problem is, when the first replace is made the length for whole string changes so at the time of replacing second string it checks for for given starting and length values but replaces in wrong position due to the first text change.